# Converting TMemoryStream to variant

Tags: delphi, memorystream, variant

How do I convert contents of a TMemoryStream to a variant? I use Delphi 2010.

TMemoryStream stores contents of a file, it can be PDF or JPG (scanned document).

File is being kept inside MS SQL base.
When I go to editing mode in my program, I extract contents of that file from base into a TMemoryStream.

After editing document's card, I need to post document back to base.
Scanned file could be changed also (or replaced with some other file).
To post record back,  I use a stored procedure with a bunch of parameters - one for every field.
I pass parameters to stored procedure as variants.

That's why I need to convert TMemoryStream to a variant.

Comment: Why are you using `Variant` to pass data to a DB?  That is not very efficient. Assuming you have wrapped the stored procedure inside of a custom function, you should use actual data types for each parameter, or at least an `array of const`, so you can preserve type information. In the case of blob fields, you can post that data using `TStream` via `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` or `TParam.AsStream`.

Comment: What format do you want to use to store it in the variant. Remember that a variant is just a container.

Comment: Remy, thanks for both of your posts. I certainly should turn my variants back into actual data types. Actually, I don't remember now why I started to treat my data as variants, so for now I have no reasons not to get things back as they were. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you need the Variant to hold an array of bytes, you can use this:

```
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  V: Variant;
  P: Pointer;
begin
  ...
  V := VarArrayCreate([0, MS.Size-1], varByte);
  if MS.Size > 0 then
  begin
    P := VarArrayLock(V);
    Move(MS.Memory^, P^, MS.Size);
    VarArrayUnlock(V);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: What will happen if `MS.size = 0` and you end up passing -1 as the second dimension to `VarArrayCreate`?

Comment: That's not a problem because we can put `if MS.Size > 0` in first place.

Comment: Setting the high bound to -1 is valid.  That is how empty arrays are created. The number of elements in the array is calculated as `highbound - lowbound + 1`, thus `-1 - 0 + 1` is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

`TMemoryStream` doesn't have a convenient way to get direct access to the internal data.  It provides a property that gives you a pointer, but not any useful data type.  However, if you use `TBytesStream`, which derives from `TMemoryStream`, you can get the data from the stream as a variable of type `TBytes`.

After this, assuming your parameter is a standard parameter object of type `TParam`, you don't need to use a variant.  You can do it like this:

```
param.AsBlob := MyTBytesVariable;
```

Or, even simpler than that, you can use the stream directly:

```
param.AsStream := MyMemoryStream;
```

(If you do this, make sure that the stream's `Position` is set to 0 first.)

Comment: `TMemoryStream` does not have a property that returns a `TBytes`. You are thinking of `TBytesStream`, which derives from `TMemoryStream`.